# How can I make a fake "active session" for gconf?

Tags: python, ubuntu, gconf, ubuntu-8.10

I've automated my Ubuntu installation - I've got Python code that runs automatically (after a clean install, but before the first user login - it's in a temporary /etc/init.d/ script) that sets up everything from Apache & its configuration to my personal Gnome preferences. It's the latter that's giving me trouble.

This worked fine in Ubuntu 8.04 (Hardy), but when I use this with 8.10 (Intrepid), the first time I try to access gconf, I get this exception:

Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://www.gnome.org/projects/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: **Not running within active session**)

Yes, right, there's no Gnome session when this is running, because the user hasn't logged in yet - however, this worked before; this appears to be new with Intrepid's Gnome (2.24?).

Short of modifying the gconf's XML files directly, is there a way to make some sort of proxy Gnome session? Or, any other suggestions?

(More details: this is python code that runs as root, but setuid's & setgid's to be me before setting my preferences using the "gconf" module from the python-gconf package.)

Answer (score 8):

I can reproduce this by installing GConf 2.24 on my machine. GConf 2.22 works fine, but 2.24 breaks it.

GConf is failing to launch because D-Bus is not running. Manually spawning D-Bus and the GConf daemon makes this work again.

I tried to spawn the D-Bus session bus by doing the following:

```
import dbus
dummy_bus = dbus.SessionBus()
```

...but got this:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: dbus-launch failed to autolaunch D-Bus session: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
```

Weird. Looks like it doesn't like to come up if X isn't running. To work around that, start dbus-launch manually (IIRC use the [os.system()](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/os-process.html) call):

```
$ dbus-launch 
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-eAmT3q94u0,guid=c250f62d3c4739dcc9a12d48490fc268
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID=15836
```

You'll need to parse the output somehow and inject them into environment variables (you'll probably want to use [os.putenv](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/os-procinfo.html)). For my testing, I just used the shell, and set the environment vars manually with `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=blahblah...`, etc.

Next, you need to launch `gconftool-2 --spawn` with those environment variables you received from `dbus-launch`. This will launch the GConf daemon. If the D-Bus environment vars are not set, the daemon will not launch.

Then, run your GConf code. Provided you set the D-Bus session bus environment variables for your own script, you will now be able to communicate with the GConf daemon.

I know it's complicated.

`gconftool-2` provides a `--direct` option that enables you to set GConf variables without needing to communicate with the server, but I haven't been able to find an equivalent option for the Python bindings (short of outputting XML manually).

*Edit:* For future reference, if anybody wants to run `dbus-launch` from within a normal `bash` script (as opposed to a Python script, as this thread is discussing), it is quite easy to retrieve the session bus address for use within the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax`

export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID

do_other_stuff_here
```

Comment: Got the same issue, setting those DBUS vars made gconf start again. Thanks!

For reference, problems started when evolution task list disappreared.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I understand the question. Looks like your script just needs to start the dbus daemon, or make sure its started. I believe "session" here refers to a dbus session. [(here is some evidence)](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/svn-commits-list/2008-May/msg01997.html), not a Gnome session. Dbus and gconf both run fine without Gnome.

Either way, faking an "active session" sounds like a pretty bad idea. It would only look for it if it needed it.

Perhaps we could see the script in a pastebin? I should have really seen it before making any comment.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Ali & Jeremy - both your answers were a big help. I'm still working on this (though I've stopped for the evening).

First, I took the hint from Ali and was trying part of Jeremy's suggestion: I was using dbus-launch to run "gconftool-2 --spawn". It didn't work for me; I now understand why (thx, Jeremy) -- I was trying to use gconf from within the same python program that was launching dbus & gconftool, but its environment didn't have the environment variables - duh.

I set that strategy aside when I noticed gconftool-2's --direct option; internally, gconftool-2 is using API that isn't exposed by the gconf python bindings. So, I modified python-gconf to expose the extra method, and once that builds (I had some unrelated problems getting this to work), we'll see if that fixes things - if it doesn't (and maybe if it does, because building those bindings seems to build all of gnome!), I'll find a better way to manage the environment variables in that first strategy.

(I'll add another answer here tomorrow either way)

And it's the next day: I ran into a little trouble with my modified python-gconf, which inspired me to try Jeremy's simpler idea, which worked fine - before doing the first gconf operation, I simply ran "dbus-launch", parsed the resulting name-value pairs, and added them directly to python's environment. Having done that, I ran "gconftool-2 --spawn". Problem solved.

Comment: If the new Python API is useful, please make sure you submit the changes upstream.